# jQuery UI Accordion in Accordion

Tags: jquery-ui, accordion

Is it possible to have an accordion embedded in another accordion with jQuery UI?

```
-Item One
-Item Two
-Item Three
  --Sub One
  --Sub Two
  --Sub Three
-Item Four
```

Where Sub One through Four is another accordion.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Give each container that you want to make an accordion a class like `accordion` and use:

`$(".accordion").accordion();`

Comment: do you have an example of this working? It doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just give different `id` names for each accordion and call them in the jquery function an you would have to edit the css to get the desired look though.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#accordion,#accordion2" ).accordion();
  });
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/yrv3dwL2/)**

Comment: Watch out. If using the 'header' option, it can break. Make sure to use the correct child selector then.