# Nested jQuery UI Accordion Not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I'm getting a collapsed menu no matter what I click. The top level works ok, it is collapsing and opening correctly. But the sub menus are not working at all. I'm not sure what the proper way to handle this is. Can anyone help?

jquery

```
 $(function() {
$( "#sectionContainer, .sectionContent" ).accordion({
  header: ".section > a",
  collapsible: true,
  active: false,
});
});
```

HTML:

```
     <div id="sectionContainer">
        <div class="section">
                <a href="#"><div class="tab active">
                    <span class="chevron"><img src="images/up.png" /></span><h3>Section 1</h3>
                </div></a> <!-- tab -->
                <ul class="sectionContent">
                    <div class="section"><a href="#"><li class="status complete"><h4>Introduction</h4></li></a>
                            <ul class="sublist"> 
                            <a href="#"><li class="status"><h6>Sub-subsection 1</h6></li></a>
                            <a href="#"><li class="status"><h6>Sub-subsection 2</h6></li></a>
                        </ul> <!-- Sub-subsections -->
                    </div> <!-- subsection -->
                    <div class="section"><a href="#"><li class="status active arrow"><h5>Subsection 1</h5></li></a>
                            <ul class="sublist"> 
                            <a href="#"><li class="status"><h6>Sub-subsection 1</h6></li></a>
                            <a href="#"><li class="status"><h6>Sub-subsection 2</h6></li></a>
                        </ul> <!-- Sub-subsections -->
                    </div> <!-- subsection -->

                    <div class="section"><a href="#"><li class="status"><h5>Subsection 3</h5></li></a>
                            <ul class="sublist"> 
                            <a href="#"><li class="status"><h6>Sub-subsection 1</h6></li></a>
                            <a href="#"><li class="status"><h6>Sub-subsection 2</h6></li></a>
                        </ul> <!-- Sub-subsections -->
                    </div> <!-- subsection -->
                    <div class="section"><a href="#"><li class="status"><h5>Review</h5></li></a>
                            <ul class="sublist"> 
                            <a href="#"><li class="status"><h6>Sub-subsection 1</h6></li></a>
                            <a href="#"><li class="status"><h6>Sub-subsection 2</h6></li></a>
                        </ul> <!-- Sub-subsections -->
                    </div> <!-- subsection -->
                </ul> <!-- sectionContent -->
        </div> <!-- section1 -->
</div> <!-- sectionContainer -->
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5723289/jquery-ui-accordion-in-accordion

Comment: I feel like there is a more simple solution than all of that code.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in your HTML markup.  As per the [documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/),

> Accordions support arbitrary markup, but each content panel must always be the next sibling after its associated header. See the header option for information on how to use custom markup structures.

So you need to make sure your accordion header and panel are siblings,

```
<div id="sectionContainer">
  <a href="#"><!-- header title --></a>
  <div class="panel">
    <div class="sectionContent">
      <a href="#"><!-- header title --></a>
      <div> class="sub-panel">
      </div>
      <a href="#"><!-- header title --></a>
      <div class="sub-panel"></div>
    </div> <!-- sectionContent -->
  </div> <!-- panel -->
</div> <!-- sectionContainer -->
```

and your script becomes,

```
$(function() {
   $("#sectionContainer, .sectionContent").accordion({
     header: " > a",
     collapsible: true,
     active: false,
   });
 });
```

I have setup a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aurovrata/1rLfqncp/3/) example that now works!

Answer (score -1):

```
 $(function() {
 $( "#sectionContainer, .sectionContent" ).accordion({
   header: ".section > a",
   collapsible: true,
   active: false, // <---
 });
 });
```

you have error "," after active: false,

should be

```
 $(function() {
 $( "#sectionContainer, .sectionContent" ).accordion({
   header: ".section > a",
   collapsible: true,
   active: false
 });
 });
```

Comment: Thank you but do you have any advice on getting it to function?

Comment: what should function do?